# How to define two variables in a loop without duplicates in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a `list` file which contains:

```
1.1.1.1:50
1.1.1.2:60
1.1.1.3:70
```

I am trying to make two variables and execute an internal application to hash the first column with the second one.  What I did is these loops, but they give me 9 possibilities and I need **only three**:

This is my script

```
#!/bin/bash
for a in $(cat list | cut -d ":" -f 1 )
do
    for b in $(cat list | cut -d ":" -f 2 )
    do
        echo $a,$b # this is example 
    done
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed 's/:/ /' list |
while read ipv4 port
do
    echo "IPv4 address: $ipv4; Port number: $port"
done
```

The only thing to be aware of is that if you set other variables in the loop, they will be run in a subshell and won't affect the rest of the script.  There are ways around that if need be (look up [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution)).

Comment: ... or simply `sed -r 's/(.*):(.*)/IPv4 address: \1; Port number: \2/' list`

Comment: @hek2mgl: Since the `echo` in the original is marked as "this is an example", the same applies to my answer.  You're right; if the objective is simply to echo data to standard output, there's no need for the loop.  It's likely that the objective is to run `wget` or `curl` or `telnet` or something using the IP address and port number, in which case the simple `sed` substitution isn't sufficient.  The port numbers don't really give the game away — they're fake too, for all practical purposes.  (The question says "running application to hash the two values".)

Comment: Good point, the echo is just an example, you are right. Just let me add that we can make use of `$IFS` instead of `sed`:  `while IFS=":" read ip port ; do echo "$ip -> $port" ; done < list`

Comment: Yes, you can use IFS too.  I tend to use `sed` or similar techniques in preference to tinkering with IFS.  I find it more robust and the cost negligible.  There are those who insist that you should do everything in the shell that can possibly be done in the shell (rather than use the shell to execute an external command) to avoid overhead.  That's fine — but I often find the concern for 'efficiency' over-rated and the reduced clarity of the script less helpful.  YMMV.

Comment: That's fine. I'm not pedantic about that. Just thought the IFS solution would be a good alternative in this case. The basic essence is to use `while read` over `for .. in`, and you showed that!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Using only shell commands, especially `while read` loops, is far more innefficient and has much more overhead than a single fork to a program that is meant for text processing, as well as often being hacky and unreadable as the shell isn't designed for text processing.